# Prometheus alert manager configuration in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, grafana, prometheus

I have i have a requirement where in the customer wants to configure some of the alerts as a mandatory ones. Below are the few parameters which iam looking to know more information about the alerts. I was trying to get the details of these parameters and iam not finding it anywhere.

```
KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch
KubeStatefulSetReplicasMismatch
KubeStatefulSetGenerationMismatch
KubeDaemonSetRolloutStuck
```

Could anyone please letme know where can i find more information regarding these parametsrs?

Answer (score 2):

You can verify the configuration into `prometheus-k8s-rulefiles-0` of `ConfigMap`.

FYI,

```
# oc get cm prometheus-k8s-rulefiles-0 -o yaml -n openshift-monitoring | \
  grep -E 'KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch|KubeStatefulSetReplicasMismatch|KubeStatefulSetGenerationMismatch|KubeDaemonSetRolloutStuck'
      - alert: KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch
      - alert: KubeStatefulSetReplicasMismatch
      - alert: KubeStatefulSetGenerationMismatch
      - alert: KubeDaemonSetRolloutStuck
```

Answer (score 0):

These are names of Prometheus alerts. You may look into this repo: https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus.

All alerts you provided are listed here: https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/prometheus-rules.yaml

**KubeStatefulSetReplicasMismatch** - StatefulSet has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.

**KubeStatefulSetGenerationMismatch** - StatefulSet generation does not match, this indicates that the StatefulSet has failed but has not been rolled back.

**KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch** - Deployment has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than an hour.

**KubeDaemonSetRolloutStuck** - Only {{ $value }}% of the desired Pods of DaemonSet are scheduled and ready.

Comment: I am looking for detailed description of the above alerts like why they are used. I am looking for some documentation where i can find all the details regarding these alerts. Could you please provide where can i can find all these above alert details in a detailed way.

Comment: I don't think there is any documentation on that. You must be familiar with Prometheus queries to understand those alerts. AFAIK, there is no detailed description of such alerts so that you can show it to your boss or somebody. But good luck with that anyway, I did what I can.

Comment: Could anyone please let me know what for these alerts used and if this alert comes  how should be troubleshoot it? Please let me know.                                                                                                                                   KubeStatefulSetReplicasMismatch
KubeStatefulSetGenerationMismatch

Answer (score 0):

As an option, can find a full alert config in a prometheus dashboard, `/rules`. Or Status->Rules menu.
[image]

The best reasoning of an alert is at the message itself, and in a runbook ref
https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/master/runbook.md